# loadChildren is deprecated in angular8

Tags: lazy-loading, dynamic-import, angular-load-children, angular8

I just noticed that Angular 8 (which will be released soon), has deprecated "string-typed router `loadChildren`". ([ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30057))

Do I understand correctly that they are refering to ...

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'production',
    loadChildren: './production/production.module#ProductionModule' // <<--this
  }],
```

To migrate to Angular 8, what is the solution ?

In the ticket they are refering to "dynamic imports". Am I correct that this refers to the following proposal:

```
let module = await import('/modules/my-module.js');
```

Could somebody give a preview of what the routing file should actually look like if we wanted to use lazy loading in the future ?

Answer (score 6):

As loadChildren:string is deprecated in angular 8 Change your loadChildren declarations

From

```
loadChildren: './production/production.module#ProductionModule'
```

To

```
loadChildren: () => import('./production/production.module').then(m => m.ProductionModule)
```

For more you can ref angular official [git link](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/30073) and [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/c61df39)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it's not the entire `"loadChildren" : ...` which is deprecated. It just will no longer accept strings. Instead you have to specify a function now.

The documentation is already available [here](https://fireship.io/snippets/lazy-loaded-routes-angular-v8-ivy/).

It comes down to:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'lazy',
    loadChildren : () => import('./production/production.module').then(m => m.ProductionModule),
  }
];
```

Comment: With the loadChildren string, you could name the lazy loaded chunk with `loadChildren: './production/production.module#ProductionModule'?chunkName=production` will we be able to do that in any way going forward? I'd like the names of the javascript files to have meaning and file names like 1.js and 2.js are meaningless.

Comment: @nephiw  Maybe you just need to update your angular version to the latest. I found this github bug report about this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14251  and there actually was a fix here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/3019ad5a56d2be8fcc69092d5935edba0e56de8c

Comment: Thanks @bvdb - currently, my build is based on webpack not the CLI; I have a very large legacy project that is a hybrid angularjs + Angular 7 and I have not figured out how to get to the CLI yet. However, I maybe able to use that issue to build a solution that will work. Thanks for the info.